# How do i paginate data from firebase. I keep getting errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code below

```
<nav v-if="(tasks.length >= 7)" aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination fw-bold justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item" @click="nextTableData"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item" v-if="(tasks.length > 14)"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
nextTableData(){
    let q
    this.spinnerShow = true
    if (this.lastdoc != null) {
        q = query(this.todosCollectionRef, orderBy("date", "desc"), startAfter(this.lastdoc));
        console.log(q, this.lastdoc);
    } else {
        q = query(this.todosCollectionRef, orderBy("date", "desc"), limit(15))
        console.log(q, this.lastdoc);
    }
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        const fbTasks = [] 
        this.lastdoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1]
            console.log(this.lastdoc); 
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const task = {
                    id: doc.id,
                    title: doc.data().title,
                    priority: doc.data().priority,
                    status: doc.data().status,
                    desc: doc.data().desc
                }
                fbTasks.push(task)
        })
            this.tasks = fbTasks
            this.spinnerShow = false
    })
}
```

I tried getting the snapshot of the lastdoc on the table from firebase and then when i click on the button i'll use the startafter method from firebase to get the data from the last doc i got, but it throws error:

> Function startAfter() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

and only the code in the else block runs

Comment: "it doesn't work" is hard to help with. It seems like `lastdoc != null` may not be getting set correctly. Did you already set breakpoints on all lines, run in a debugger, and check why that isn't happening?

Comment: this is the error i get. Function startAfter() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined. Sorry i've edited my question. How do you mean by it not getting set correctly.

Comment: It looks like your `lastDoc` is `undefined` and not `null`, so this doesn't work: `if (this.lastdoc != null) {`. Instead do `if (this.lastdoc) {`.

Comment: i did use if (this.lastdoc) it was the same error. So i tried with null.  if (this.lastdoc) is literally the same response

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve this myself by extensively going through the firebase docs and using the getDocs method. Which gets the snapshot of the last doc on the page and using the startAfter method to view the next set of data. Kindly view below:

```
async nextTableData(){
        this.spinnerShow = true
        const documentSnapshots = await getDocs(this.todosCollectionQuery);

        // Get the last visible document
        const lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
        console.log("last", lastVisible);

        // Construct a new query starting at this document,
        const next = query(this.todosCollectionRef, orderBy("date", "desc"), startAfter(lastVisible), limit(10));

        onSnapshot(next, (querySnapshot) => {
            const fbTasks = [] 
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const task = {
                        id: doc.id,
                        title: doc.data().title,
                        priority: doc.data().priority,
                        status: doc.data().status,
                        desc: doc.data().desc
                    }
                    fbTasks.push(task)
            })
                this.tasks = fbTasks
                this.spinnerShow = false
        })
    }
```